# Where do hash functions get their preimage resistance?

Tags: hash, preimage-resistance

I read through [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/why-are-hash-functions-one-way-if-i-know-the-algorithm-why-cant-i-calculate-t/19658#19658) and it seemed to make sense to me, but when I try to make a simpler answer to explain it to myself I lose something in the process.

Here is the much simpler hash function I wrote after reading the description of how MD5 works.

1. Take in a single digit integer input as `M`
2. Define `A[0]` to be some public constant
3. `for int i=1; i<=4; i++:`
   `A[i] = (A[i-1] + M) mod 10`
4. return `A[4]`

This hash function uses the message word in multiple rounds, which is what the answer says leads to preimage resistance.  But with some algebra using [mod addition](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/modular-addition-and-subtraction) we can reduce this "hash function" to just `A[i] = (A[0] + i*M) mod 10`.

```
A[1] = (A[0] + M) mod 10
A[2] = (A[1] + M) mod 10    //Substitute A[1] in
     = ((A[0] + M) mod 10 + M) mod 10   // Distribute outer mod 10 in
     = ((A[0] + M) mod 10 mod 10 + M mod 10) mod 10 // simplify mod 10 mod 10 to mod 10
     = ((A[0] + M) mod 10 + M mod 10) mod 10    // Distribute inner mod 10
     = ((A[0] mod 10 + M mod 10) mod 10 + M mod 10) mod 10  //factor mod 10 out
     = ((A[0] mod 10 + M mod 10) + M) mod 10    // remove redudent paraens
     = (A[0] mod 10 + M mod 10 + M) mod 10  // factor mod 10 in
     = (A[0] mod 10 mod 10 + M mod 10 mod 10 + M mod 10) mod 10 // simplify mod 10 mod 10 to mod 10
     = (A[0] mod 10 + M mod 10 + M mod 10) mod 10   // factor mods 10 out
     = (A[0] + M + M) mod 10
     = (A[0] + 2M) mod 1
// Repeat with A[3] to find A[3] = (A[0] + 3M) mod 10 and so on
```

Because `A[i] = (A[0] + i*M) mod 10` is not preimage resistant, I'm confused as to what action in a hash function gives it its preimage resistance. To phrase my question another way, if I wanted to write a super simple hash function, what would I need to include to be preimage resistant?

Comment: In short, the compression prevent the pre-image attack.

Comment: Note, however, that collision resistance or one-wayness is always assumed and never proved (proving that one-way function exists would be a mayor breakthrough in computer science)

Comment: Do you think you could explain more about how compression leads to pre-image resistance?  As an example, this function `h(x) = (x[0] + x[1]) mod 10` (where `x` is a two digit integer, `x[0]` is the first digit, and `x[1]` is the second digit) isn't pre-image resistant despite compressing two digits worth of data into one.